# where to put jquery id click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Within my ajax success function, I have the following code:

```
$('#searchButton').on('click',function(){
//ajax call
//within that ajax call's success function:
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'search.php',      
      data: {x:x},        
      success:function(dataReturn){              

        $('#returnThree').html(
        "<img id='expandThree' class='expandThree' src='../../img/expand.png'>"
        );
```

I have another function that I want to be called when the user clicks on this image, but I can't figure out where to put the code as nothing seems to work:

```
$("#expandThree").click(function() {
  console.log('hi');
  });
```

I've tried putting it both inside and outside of the `$('#searchButton').on('click',function(){`, but it's not calling.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use $(document).on('click',"#expandThree",function(){});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on your `success` callback:

```
var $img = $("<img id='expandThree' class='expandThree' src='../../img/expand.png'>")
               .appendTo('#returnThree')
               .on("click", function() {});
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gpnbwvq6/)**</kbd>